# How to display a string with new line character in a HTML page using scriplets?

Tags: html, jsp, scriptlet

```
<% 
String a="abc";
Srting b="xyz";
String c=a+"\n"+b;
%>
```

I want to display `String c` in a HTML table like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><%= c %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to get this:

```
--------
| abc  |
| xyz  |
--------
```

But I get this:

```
------------
| abc xyz  |
------------
```

Is there anything I could do with the scriplet to acheive this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Html has`<br>`tag for page breaks. So you can insert it in java code instead of `\n`:

```
String c=a+"<br>"+b;
```

Comment: Thanks.. It worked.. I thought it would display as abc<br>xyz

Comment: A doubt.. @Nailgun.. If I want to display abc<br>xyz.. How can I do it?

Comment: @Rey Rajesh `String c=a+"&lt;br&gt;"+b;`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `<br/>` instead of `"\n"`

> String c=a+`"<br/>"`+b;

Answer (score 1):

From your design ,

You can simply make it as,

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><%= a %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><%= b %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

to display it in the rows . Using `<br/>` in the table is meaningless.

If your intent is to display the multi-line `td`,

1. [How to show multiline text in a table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937218/how-to-show-multiline-text-in-a-table-cell)
2. [Width of a <td> is narrower when I use a <br> in it on a fixed width <table>. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812602/width-of-a-td-is-narrower-when-i-use-a-br-in-it-on-a-fixed-width-table-wh)

Also scriptlets are discouraged over the decade . Please read [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)